# Original error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Tags: android, appium, karate

When I run karate testing with appium it gives this error

I installed :
Android-studio
appium
node
npm

```
  Original error: pkg: /data/local/tmp/appium_cache/31bc49edb643a4a324f739a34babfd1e6d522a16.apk\r\nFailure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]"},


  Full error msg:
    ExamplesTest driver config / start failed: webdriver session 
    create status 500, {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An 
    unknown server-side error occurred while processing the 
    command. Original error: pkg: 
     /data/local/tmp/
      appium_cache/31bc49edb643a4a324f739a34babfd1e6d522a16 
      .apk\r\nFailure 
      [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]"},"sessionId":null}, options: 
      {type=android, webDriverPath=/wd/hub, start=true, 
      httpConfig={readTimeout=120000}, target=null, 
      webDriverSession={desiredCapabilities= 
      {app=/home/yabesh/Downloads/UiDemo.apk, 
      newCommandTimeout=300, platformVersion=5.1, 
      platformName=Android, connectHardwareKeyboard=true, 
      deviceName=emulator-554, avd=Nexus_4_API_22, 
       automationName=UiAutomator2}}}
      classpath:test/test_features/android/android.feature:28
```

how to resolve that.please help me.

Comment: let me say that appium support in karate is experimental. if you or your team can contribute, please do so. that said - there are many teams that use it - so you can evaluate it and take a decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue Sorted Out:**

I found and sort out this issue. The problem is with the Android emulator configurations currently running. After reconfiguring the emulator the error disappeared and ran without any problem.